# What is the advantage of Ranged Legerdemain for Sleight of Hand?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, class-feature, prestige-class

This may be obvious, but what are the advantages to using the Arcane Trickster's [Ranged Legerdemain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/arcane-trickster#TOC-Ranged-Legerdemain-Su-) ability for a Sleight of Hand check.

I would assume IF they noticed the object in question you yourself would not be (since you're no where near said object). Which also brings the question if they notice can you notice them noticing the object and stop the process?

Answer (score 5):

For one, Disable Device at 30ft means disabling traps while being outside of the "oh crap" range for most traps, so that even if you fail you'll most likely escape unharmed.

Sleight of Hand means you can steal the keys off a guard through the bars of a prison, or pick an item off a table through a window, or steal someone's hat from a side-alley and many other things.

Unless the item in question is hidden in a pocket, you can probably get your hands on it at range without being suspicious. Often even approaching the thing you want to snatch calls attention to yourself, which you will now avoid.

Also, technically it doesn't even mention you have to be able to see the item to steal, so you could probably even pickpocket someone from 30ft away.

And I'm guessing the higher DC includes moving the item to your hand through the air; so that if you beat the check they don't notice the item moving and have no option to stop you.

All in all, it seems there's plenty of situations where these ranged skills would come in useful.